# Counting the times numbers occur in an array using (count_numbers(int [], int, int)) C

Tags: c, arrays, count

So what I have is an array that's size is decided by me and then the elements in the array are randomly generated. It's supposed to take an integer array,its size, and an integer number 
and find how many times the number is present in the array and return that count at the end.I keep trying stuff and nothing seems to be getting me anywhere close to an answer. I was just trying to see if someone could point me in the right direction on where to start

```
count_numbers(int array[], int size, int z)
```

Comment: And where is the implementation of count_numbers? and that is the problem with it?

Comment: I don't really have anything, everything I tried I couldn't get to do anything so I mostly just want someone to point me in the direction of just how to start this

Comment: but we will not do your homework. try it and show us that you tried it and ask specific questions

Comment: This is trivial. Just loop over your array incrementing a counter everytime the array's value is equal to z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hhave you tried running a loop through the array and trying a match expression to the array value in another loop. This seems like a logic question rather than actual code related. Maybe a search around the internet looking at how to count in arrays could help you.

This should point you in the right direction...

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
  if (array[i] == z /*z being your search value**/) { 

  you may have to alter this a little
  //dosomething 

  // e.g. increment a count here 
}
else
  do-nothing essentially.
```

There is a method for checking array size - so don't worry about defining it's size. have a look at the java method for this and use it.

Hope this helps